# How to get a sf with line segments from a data table?

Tags: r, sf

Given the following code:

```
library(data.table)

x<-runif(10)
y<-runif(10)
dt<-data.table( someAtt=sample(c("a","b","c"),10,replace = T), 
   long=x, lat=y, prevLong=shift(x), prevLat=shift(y) )
```

The resulting data.table looks as follows:

```
    a       long        lat   prevLong    prevLat
 1: a 0.07082431 0.78423301         NA         NA
 2: b 0.71443287 0.36526340 0.07082431 0.78423301
 3: c 0.09045303 0.67790574 0.71443287 0.36526340
 4: d 0.11502144 0.28482632 0.09045303 0.67790574
 5: e 0.32395554 0.03948988 0.11502144 0.28482632
 6: f 0.22150591 0.94228135 0.32395554 0.03948988
 7: g 0.83432081 0.12126201 0.22150591 0.94228135
 8: h 0.48438370 0.96476431 0.83432081 0.12126201
 9: i 0.55442422 0.55877777 0.48438370 0.96476431
10: j 0.42999165 0.48831255 0.55442422 0.55877777
```

The data.table/data.frame consists of some attribute and longitude/latitude information. prevLong and prevLat represent the longitude/latitude of the previous row.

What I want is a sf object consisting of 10 line segmenets, each line segment defined by the longitude/latitude information of the rows.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple conversion - you don't need the extra columns, just the lat/long of each vertex in the line:

```
line <- dt[, 2:3] %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  st_linestring() %>%
  st_sfc() %>%
  st_sf()
```

edit: wait, if you wanted each line segment on a separate row of your final sf,

```
ptmat <- dt[, 2:5] %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  .[2:nrow(.), ]

linesegs <- split(ptmat, 1:nrow(ptmat)) %>%
  lapply(., function(x) {
    x <- matrix(x, nrow = 2, byrow = T)
    x <- st_linestring(x)}) 

final_sf <- st_sfc(linesegs ) %>% 
  st_sf('ID' = 1:length(.))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `st_linestring` function from `sf` package:

```
library(data.table)
library(sf)

x<-runif(10)
y<-runif(10)
dt<-data.table(someAtt=sample(c("a","b","c"),10,replace = T), 
                long=x, lat=y, prevLong=shift(x), prevLat=shift(y) )
###(i couln't get it to run with an empty c(), so the
### first value was made before the loop
temp <- st_linestring(rbind(c(dt$long[1], dt$lat[1]), c(dt$prevLong[1], dt$prevLat[1])))
ls <- c(temp)
for(i in 1:dim(dt)[1]){
  temp2 <- st_linestring(rbind(c(dt$long[i], dt$lat[i]), c(dt$prevLong[i], dt$prevLat[i])))
  ls <- c(ls, temp2)
}     

plot(ls)
```

because of the data, lines appear connected

Comment: I feel more context is needed for this to be an answer--there is no explanation as to why the OP's code is wrong and this is correct. This also appears to be a hardcoded answer--dependent upon the data that OP provided and not something usable for the next person who needs to split into x amount of line segments.